# WPF Project cannot find system.web Assembly

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add System.Web as a reference if I cant find it in the list of references?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5208862/how-do-i-add-system-web-as-a-reference-if-i-cant-find-it-in-the-list-of-referenc)

I am developing `wpf` application.

I am using one of the `system.web` class called `HttpUtility`.

I am not able to add the reference.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adjust your `Target Framework` to .NET Framework 4.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, so user have to download 20mb more of .net framework.